# Sharing variables between WordPress and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, authentication, cookies

Currently I want to share a variable (cookie) between a WordPress (WP) application and CodeIgniter (CI) application.

Both application have the same hosting:

- the WP application is using the domain,
- and the CI application is using the sub-domain.

They both share the same database, and tables.

The main problem I am trying to solve is that I do not want the users to use the same credentials to login the WP, and later on the CI. Once they are login on WP, they do not need to login again on CI ... the same goes for the other way around.

I did some searching, and came on couple of solutions but I didn't understand them, that is why I decide to ask the StackOverflow community.

Any help, a link, description, answer is appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set domain in cookie.
For your application requires cookies to have a domain in the field of the primary domain. in this case, the cookie will be available on the primary domain and subdomains. Set domain in cookie = main domain. Do same in wp and ci apps.

From php.net
domain
The (sub)domain that the cookie is available to. Setting this to a subdomain (such as 'www.example.com') will make the cookie available to that subdomain and all other sub-domains of it (i.e. w2.www.example.com). To make the cookie available to the whole domain (including all subdomains of it), simply set the value to the domain name ('example.com', in this case).

Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.